# Abrir WebCam e capturar imagem com C# em ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

tudo bem? Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de cadastro de alunos e preciso abrir a webcam do computador para tirar uma foto do aluno e vincular no seu cadastro, gostaria de saber como é possível realizar essa ação utilizando C# em ASP.NET WebForm.
Desde já, muito obrigado!

Comment: Conseguiu avançar?

Comment: Infelizmente não meu amigo, ele apenas abre como um input type="file" normal, eu precisava de uma solução que abrisse a webcam utilizando qualquer meio que envolvesse ASP.NET ou Javascript, já consegui porém realizar a abertura da WebCam, porém ainda estou tendo dificuldades em capturar a imagem, mas estou no caminho, de qualquer maneira agradeço ao amigo pela boa disposição de ajudar. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Você pode simplesmente usar um input file com o atributo `capture`, se o dispositivo estiver disponível e o acesso for liberado pelo usuário a captura será feito por ela, caso contrário irá abrir o diálogo para seleção do arquivo nos diretórios locais

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture>
```